# AD FS claims not provided to id_token

Tags: openid, adfs, windows-server-2022

I'm stumped. Adding claims for my application in Application Groups is not working.
I'm using Windows Server 2022.

[Application Groups -> TestApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt8xU.png)

[TestApp - Web API -> Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOJ8C.png)

[Issuance Transform Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcj7l.png)

[Edit Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urdsx.png)

The screenshots show the process of adding claims, but after my actions I still do not see the extended information in the id_token, received during the authorization process. Can someone help and explain why this mechanism does not work. Thank you!